# How to pass a value from shell script to C program

Tags: c, shell

I am trying to use system() in C to call shell script to modify a file and execute a executable file and get some output in another directory (not the C working directory). How can I pass the value I got in the shell script to the main C program. Thanks in advance!

```
#define shell "\
#/bin/bash \n\
cd home/path \n\
"input modification" \n\
./ exe \n\ #output a parameter b in the file out
b=$(cat <out) \n\
echo "b" \n\
"
void main()
{
 system(shell);
 printf("b=d%",b);
}
```

Comment: You might want to read about the [`popen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) function.

Comment: Oh, and [`system`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) is equivalent to do `/bin/sh -c "..."` in a shell, so if you try to actually use your macro `SHELLSCRIPT` then it won't work very well.

Comment: Finally, to dynamically build a string in C then use [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Answer (score 2):

First problem:

The best way is to create a temporary file that contains your shell script and execute it. For example you can create it *via* `tmpnam`/`creat` to get a filename, create the file and open it. Then, you have to fill its content with your shell script instructions and use `system` to execute it after having modify its permissions to execute it (see `chmod`).

Second problem:

To receive data from a subprocess you need to establish some communication, either by writing/reading in a file, or using a pipe for example. A pipe can be easily established using `popen` in place of `system`.

Finally, don't forget to remove every temporary object.

Comment: Thanks! Could you just give a very simple pseudo code here for solving the problem?